# How to configure Hardware RAID PCI VT6421?

Tags: 18.04, server, hardware, configuration, pci

I am playing with an Ubuntu 18.04 Home Server for some time now and found this RAID controller VT6421. I am not very experienced with configuring hardware in Ubuntu and was not able to find a solution here or on Google.

How do I configure such PCI devices like the RAID controller?

I have only access to a cli over SSH. The two hard disks attached to the RAID controller are visible, but separate for the server. The server uses a kernel driver `sata_via` for the RAID controller, how can I tell it to use the two disks as RAID? VT6421 supports RAID 0 and 1.

EDIT1:

```
lspci | grep -i raid
```

just the one controller

```
02:01.0 RAID bus controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6421 IDE/SATA Controller (rev 50)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lspci | grep -i raid`